# Trouble with SOAP call in Azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, soap, azure-data-factory

I've been having some difficulty trying to get this SOAP API to run inside Azure Data Factory. I am pretty new to XML and SOAP in general, so I've been hitting roadblocks daily.

I am getting this when I run preview data in the Source data of the Copy Data object in the pipeline.

[image]

I have also been trying to run this through SOAP UI and get a credentials error. I have no reason to believe that my username/PW is wrong since its just a newly created service account.
[image]

Can anyone help with this? Not even sure what other information to provide as I'm pretty lost.

Thanks!

EDIT:
@jdweng, my previous SOAP body attempt is as follows:
[image]

EDIT 2:
@jdweng, I'm using this as my current headers:
[image]

Comment: SOAP is XML.  Your body is JSON which is not allowed.  When you use authentication there are two request.  First request get a token in the response.  Then token is used with second request.  You may need to authenticate with json on first request.  Then use token in second request which is XML SOAP

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I should mention that I've attempted many different formats and this is the latest one to fail. The code you are referencing is what I got from using SOAP UI. My previous attempts do use SOAP code in the body which I'll edit into the OP cause the code is too long for a comment.

Comment: A SOAP is a HTTP request and has headers.  The Soap is the HTTP Request body. You need an authorization header like following : https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/faq/how-to-send-a-soap-request-with-the-oauth-authoriz/

Comment: @jdweng I do have a header I've been using but didn't include here. I'll say that an authorization header is new to me. I'm using the username/password as a basic authentication type in my Data Factory linked service. See edit to OP - I pasted the header I'm currently using and highlighted the lines that I have been suggested to include in another source (https://medium.com/@gabrielsribe/consuming-a-soap-service-using-azure-data-factory-copy-data-activity-a4a3332cc4c) 

Do I still need to add an auth header?

Comment: You preview data is JSON.  Not XML.  Soap is XML.  You request can be SOAP and the response can be anything including text, json, XML.  Your body is null.  You just saying you are having trouble but you are not giving the error.  Also the body (contents) can be compressed using GZIP.  You have header than is automatically uncompress the body.  Are you getting a status of 200 OK in response?  You say you are getting credential issues.  There is more than one type of Authentication and client and server has to use same type of Authentication.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, my Preview Data picture is what happens when I attempt to view the data using the connection in Data Factory. Unless there is a better way to test, my expectation there is some of the data that is pulling from the API. Yes the body is null, I imagine that would be an indicator of the API call not functioning correctly because I'm expecting data to show? I would love to show you a specific error, but aside from the null body and the SOAP UI (white photo above) showing a faultstring, I have no specific error number to provide. Any ideas how to better test to provide an error?

Comment: You have a frontend which is the HTTP connection between the client and the server (SOAP).  You have a backend which is the connection from server to database.   The front end is working since you got a response.  So the issue is query between server and database is not returning any data.  There doesn't look like there is any query in the SOAP which may be the issue.  It looks like the SOAP is a template and missing sections.  the following shows an example where MULTIPLY is done : https://www.how2code.info/en/blog/how-to-connect-to-a-soap-api-from-azure-data-factory/

Comment: @jdweng I actually did find the link you provided before I made this topic and still wasn't able to get it working. The query, I think, is included, its the part in the above screenshots that says <SearchRecordsByReport> and this command references a specific report GUID that contains the data I'm trying to fetch.

Comment: See following.  In Step one you send a SOAP and get back a Session ID.  The you take the Session ID in step one and add to Step two : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165078/how-the-pass-a-session-id-for-a-soap-api-in-adf