# SOAP issues - attempting to get API running in Postman (Error 415)

Tags: soap, postman

I'm new to using SOAP API's and having some difficulty getting it working inside Postman. I created [another thread a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854919/trouble-with-soap-call-in-azure-data-factory?noredirect=1) and wasn't able to resolve my issue. I'm back now with Postman ready to go to hopefully figure out exactly what the problem is with my API.

I figure if I can get it running in Postman, I can then attempt to move it over into the end-goal area: Azure Data Factory. I'm trying to use an Archer API, so my expected return is a block of data that I use in one of my Power BI reports.

Here is my current setup:

**Headers:**
[image: header]

And Content-Type has a longer entry:
[image]

**Here is the body:**
[image]

I'm passing the username/PW in via basic authorization. I have tested and confirmed that I can login to the Archer account using these credentials.
[image]

**My current error:**
[image]

Kinda lost here since I have about a week experience using SOAP API's. Anyone know what the issue could be?

(@jdweng from the previous thread)